# Xubuntu - manually restart network after reboot?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, xubuntu

I am running Xubuntu (12.04 LTS) and something is wrong with my network settings (for wireless network using DHCP and WPA). Whenever I reboot, after the access to the network is not working unless I restart the network or at least the wlan0 interface:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0
sudo ifup wlan0
```

The configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces` seems to be correct, because when I restart networking it is working correctly. Any ideas?

EDIT:

In the panel the network manager shows the wireless networks as 'not managed', before and after restarting the network.

Comment: We will need to know what kind of wireless card you have and as much detailed information as possible about your system.

Comment: The wireless card is from Intel (3945ABG, Golan) which seems to be [supported](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsIntel). The machine has Intel Core 2 CPU and runs kernel version 3.2.0-53-generic and Ubuntu 12.04 with Xfce Desktop Environment v4.8.

Comment: Im guessing you want NetworkManager to manage your connection as this is the norm on most laptops if so you shouldn’t be using `/etc/network/interfaces` I'd remove all references to wlan[?] from there. Reboot and list if network manager panel is showing your connected etc..

Comment: Perfect, this actually solved my problem and it is automatically connecting now using the network manager. Thanks!

Comment: Okay i'll add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 2):

Im guessing you want network-manager to manage your connection as this is the norm on most laptops if so you shouldn’t be using `/etc/network/interfaces` I'd remove all references to `wlan[?]` from their and reboot.